# UWP TabView OneWay x:Bind does not update

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a `TabView` whose `ItemTemplate` is like this:

```
<controls:TabView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Playlist">
        <local:HeaderedPlaylistControl
            IsPlaylist="True"
            Loaded="HeaderedPlaylistControl_Loaded"
            MusicCollection="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:TabView.ItemTemplate>
```

This is part of the `HeaderedPlaylistControl`:

```
<local:PlaylistControl
    AllowReorder="False"
    AlternatingRowColor="True"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind MusicCollection.Songs, Mode=OneWay}">
    <local:PlaylistControl.Header>
        <controls:ScrollHeader Mode="Sticky">
            <UserControl>
                <Grid
                    x:Name="PlaylistInfoGrid"
                    Padding="10"
                    Background="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image
                        x:Name="PlaylistCover"
                        Grid.RowSpan="3"
                        Width="180"
                        Height="180"
                        Margin="20"
                        Source="Assets/monotone_bg_wide.png" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="PlaylistNameTextBlock"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="36"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{x:Bind MusicCollection.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="PlaylistInfoTextBlock"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,5"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Text="{x:Bind MusicCollection.Songs, Converter={StaticResource SongCountConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </controls:ScrollHeader>
    </local:PlaylistControl.Header>
</local:PlaylistControl>
```

When I switch between tabs, the `HeaderedPlaylistControl` doesn't update it's content. Why is that?

Is it because of the `MusicCollection` property (it is of type `Playlist`) doesn't notify the binding when switching tabs? If so, where should I put the notification? The definition of `Playlist` is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Models/Playlist.cs).

HeaderedPlaylistControl is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/HeaderedPlaylistControl.xaml.cs):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you suspected, the problem is that the `MusicCollection` property is an ordinary property which does not notify about changes. To make your code work, you need to make the `MusicCollection` property a dependency property (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview)). This is a kind of properties which are best for data-bound properties of visual controls and have many additional features as well.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MusicCollectionProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(MusicCollection), typeof(Playlist),
        typeof(HeaderedPlaylistControl), null
    );

public Playlist MusicCollection
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(MusicCollectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MusicCollectionProperty, value); }
}
```